# How can I use NtQueryInformationThread to find a stack's base address?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to search for a specific integer valued stored in another process by scanning its memory. I enumerate its threads, and I want to find the base address of the thread so I can start searching byte by byte for the integer value. I'm not sure about the feasibility of this strategy, as I read somewhere this may not be the "real" stack address.

I did some digging around and found a (forbidden) NtQueryInformationThread in the undocumented section of msdn. I understand it's unstable and obsolete, but in the little information I've scraped together it seems the only "simple" way.

```
NTSTATUS queryThread = NtQueryInformationThread(hThread, (THREADINFOCLASS)ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress, &startAddress, sizeof(startAddress), sizeRequested);
```

My issue is that when I specify `ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress`, I always get a warning that:

> `ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress` is undefined.

In another forum I saw a user define it as "9".

Comment: `NtQueryInformationThread` not *unstable* and not *obsolete*. `ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress` defined in *ntddk.h*. but what you try get - thread start address or thread current stack high/low limits ? this is absolute different things

Comment: I'm trying to get the thread start address https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationthread, from there I want to start searching for an integer value.  I believe I'll also need to find when the stack ends.  I'll look into including ntddk.h file for `ThreadQuerySetWin32StarAddress`.  In the snippets I've found, I've never seen that header file used though.

Comment: for get stack limits - use `ThreadBasicInformation` and get `TebBaseAddress`- pointer to `NT_TIB`

Comment: Thread start address won't help. That's the address of code.